# JS thumbnail slider not working with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

This is my JSP page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#carouselh').jsCarousel({  autoscroll: false, circular: true, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 5, orientation: 'h' });

    });  

    function change()
 {
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'demoo.jsp',
            data: { },
            success: function(result)
            {

          document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=result;
             }
        });
    }




        </script>

 </head>

 <body>
    <button onclick="change()">Click Me!</button>

    <div id="main"> 
             </div>

 </body>

     <script src="js/jsCarousel-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link href="css/jsCarousel-2.0.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
 </html>
```

This is my demoo.jsp page:

```
  <div id="carouselh">
  <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/lapi_large.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;"  /><br />
                            </div>
                        <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/mobile_small.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;"  /><br />
                            </div>
                        <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/lapi_large.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;"  /><br />
                            </div>
                        <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/mobile_small.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;"  /><br />
                            </div>
                        <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/lapi_large.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;" /><br />
                            </div>
                        <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/mobile_small.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;"  /><br />
                            </div>
      <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/mobile_small.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;"  /><br />
                            </div>
      <div>
                            <img alt="" src="images/mobile_small.jpg" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;float: left;"  /><br />
                            </div>


  </div>
```

Here is jsCarousel-2.0.0.js:

```
 (function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    jsCarousel: function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            scrollspeed: 1500,
            delay: 5000,
            itemstodisplay: 5,
            autoscroll: false,
            circular: false,
            masked: true,
            orientation: 'h'
        }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var oclass = 'horizontal';
            if (settings.orientation == 'v')
                oclass = 'vertical';
            var slidercontents = $(this).addClass('jscarousal-contents-' + oclass + '');
            var slider = $('<div/>').addClass('jscarousal-' + oclass + '').attr('id', slidercontents.attr('id'));
            var backbutton = $('<div/>').addClass('jscarousal-' + oclass + '-back');
            var forwardbutton = $('<div/>').addClass('jscarousal-' + oclass + '-forward');

            slidercontents.removeAttr('id');
            slidercontents.before(slider);
            slider.append(backbutton);
            slider.append(slidercontents);
            slider.append(forwardbutton);

            var total = $('> div', slidercontents).css('display', 'none').length;
            var index = 0;
            var start = 0;
            var current = $('<div/>');
            var noOfBlocks;
            var interval;
            var display = settings.itemstodisplay;
            var speed = settings.scrollspeed;
            var top;
            var left;
            var height;
            var containerHeight;
            var containerWidth;
            var direction = "forward";
            var scrolling = true;

            function initialize() {
                index = -1;
                noOfBlocks = parseInt(total / display);
                if (total % display > 0) noOfBlocks++;
                index = noOfBlocks - 1;
                var startIndex = 0;
                var endIndex = display;
                var copy = false;
                var allElements = $('> div', slidercontents);
                $('> div', slidercontents).remove();
                if (settings.masked)
                    allElements.addClass('thumbnail-inactive').hover(function() {   $(this).removeClass('thumbnail-inactive').addClass('thumbnail-active'); }, function() {   $(this).removeClass('thumbnail-active').addClass('thumbnail-inactive'); })
                for (var i = 0; i < noOfBlocks; i++) {
                    if (total > display) {
                        startIndex = i * display;
                        endIndex = startIndex + display;
                        if (endIndex > total) {
                            startIndex -= (endIndex - total);
                            endIndex = startIndex + display;
                            copy = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        startIndex = 0;
                        endIndex = total;
                    }
                    var wrapper = $('<div/>')
                    allElements.slice(startIndex, endIndex).each(function(index, el) {
                        if (!copy)
                            wrapper.append(el);
                        else wrapper.append($(el).clone(true));
                    });

                    slidercontents.append(wrapper);
                }
                if (settings.onthumbnailclick != null)
                    $('> div > div', slidercontents).css('cursor', 'pointer');

                $('> div', slidercontents).addClass('hidden');
                $('> div > div', slidercontents).css('display', '');

                /*vertical*/
                if (settings.orientation == 'v') {
                    top = $('> div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).css('top');
                    if (top == 'auto') top = "0px";
                    containerHeight = slidercontents.height();
                    height = slidercontents.get(0).offsetHeight;
                    $('> div', slidercontents).css('top', '-' + containerHeight + 'px');
                    $('> div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).stop(false, true).animate({ 'top': top }, speed, function() { scrolling = false; });
                }
                /*horizontal*/
                if (settings.orientation == 'h') {
                    left = $('> div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).css('left');
                    containerWidth = slidercontents.width();
                    height = slidercontents.get(0).offsetHeight;
                    $('> div', slidercontents).css('left', '-' + containerWidth + 'px');
                    $('> div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).stop(false, true).animate({ left: 0 }, speed, function() { scrolling = false; });
                }
                $('> div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');

                slider.mouseenter(function() { if (settings.autoscroll) stopAnimate(); }).mouseleave(function() { if (settings.autoscroll) animate(); });
                if (settings.autoscroll)
                    animate();
                forwardbutton.click(function() {
                    if (!scrolling) {
                        direction = "forward";
                        if (settings.circular)
                            if (index <= 0) index = noOfBlocks;
                        showThumbs();
                    }
                });
                backbutton.click(function() {
                    if (!scrolling) {
                        direction = "backward";
                        if (settings.circular)
                            if (index >= noOfBlocks - 1) index = -1;
                        showThumbs();
                    }
                });
            }
            initialize();
            function stopAnimate() {
                scrolling = false;
                clearTimeout(interval);
                slider.children().clearQueue();
                slider.children().stop(false, true);
            }
            function animate() {                    
                clearTimeout(interval);
                if (settings.autoscroll)
                    interval = setTimeout(changeSlide, settings.delay);
            }
            function changeSlide() {
                if (direction == "forward") {
                    if (index <= 0) index = noOfBlocks;
                } else {
                    if (index >= noOfBlocks - 1) { index = -1; }
                }
                showThumbs();
                interval = setTimeout(changeSlide, settings.delay);
            }
            function getDimensions(value) {
                return value + 'px';
            }
            function showThumbs() {
                scrolling = true;
                var current = $('.visible', slidercontents);
                var scrollSpeed = speed;

                if (direction == "forward") {
                    index--;
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        if (settings.orientation == 'v') {
                            $('>div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).css('top', getDimensions(containerHeight)).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible').stop(false, true).animate({ 'top': top }, scrollSpeed, function() { scrolling = false; });
                            current.stop(false, true).animate({ 'top': '-=' + getDimensions(containerHeight) }, scrollSpeed, function() {
                                $(this).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
                                $(this).css('top', top);
                                scrolling = false;
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            $('>div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).css('left', getDimensions(containerWidth)).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible').stop(false, true).animate({ 'left': '-=' + getDimensions(containerWidth) }, scrollSpeed, function() { scrolling = false; });
                            current.stop(false, true).animate({ 'left': '-=' + getDimensions(containerWidth) }, scrollSpeed, function() {
                                $(this).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
                                $(this).css('left', left);
                                scrolling = false;
                            });
                        }
                    } else index = 0;

                }
                else if (direction == "backward") {
                    index++;
                    if (index < noOfBlocks) {
                        if (settings.orientation == 'v') {
                            $('>div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible').css({
                                'top': getDimensions(-containerHeight)
                            }).stop(false, true).animate({ 'top': top }, scrollSpeed, function() { scrolling = false; });

                            current.stop(false, true).animate({ 'top': '+=' + getDimensions(containerHeight) }, scrollSpeed,
                        function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
                            $(this).css('top', getDimensions(-containerHeight));
                            scrolling = false;
                        });
                        }
                        else {
                            $('>div:eq(' + index + ')', slidercontents).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible').css({
                                'left': getDimensions(-containerWidth)
                            }).stop(false, true).animate({ 'left': '+=' + getDimensions(containerWidth) }, scrollSpeed, function() { scrolling = false; });

                            current.stop(false, true).animate({ 'left': '+=' + getDimensions(containerWidth) }, scrollSpeed,
                        function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
                            $(this).css('left', getDimensions(-containerWidth));
                            scrolling = false;
                        });
                        }

                    } else index = noOfBlocks - 1;
                }

            }
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Here is my jsCarousel-2.0.0.css:

﻿
       .jscarousal-horizontal
       {
        width: 450px;
      height: 118px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

```
    position: relative; /*overflow: hidden;*/
  }
  .jscarousal-horizontal-back, .jscarousal-horizontal-forward
   {
  float: left;
  width: 23px;
  height: 98px;
  color: White;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .jscarousal-horizontal-back
 {
 background-image: url(../images/left_arrow.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
 }
 .jscarousal-horizontal-forward
 {
 background-image: url(../images/right_arrow.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right;
 }
 .jscarousal-contents-horizontal
 {
  float: left;
height: 95px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 403px;
margin-top:10px;
 }
.jscarousal-contents-horizontal > div
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 124px;
 }
 .jscarousal-contents-horizontal > div > div
{
float: left;
margin-left: 7px;
margin-right: 7px;
 }
.jscarousal-contents-horizontal img
 {
width: 120px;
height: 94px;
border: solid 1px #7A7677;
}

.jscarousal-vertical
{
width: 140px;
height: 460px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.jscarousal-vertical-back, .jscarousal-vertical-forward
{
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background-color: #121212;
color: White;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
z-index:100;
 }
```

.jscarousal-vertical-back
    {
    background-image: url(top_arrow.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    }
    .jscarousal-vertical-forward
    {
    background-image: url(bottom_arrow.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
     }
    .jscarousal-contents-vertical
    {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 140px;
    height: 410px;
     }
    .jscarousal-contents-vertical > div
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 820px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jscarousal-contents-vertical > div > div
     {
    width: 130px;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 8px;
    margin-left: 14px;
     }
     .jscarousal-contents-vertical > div > div span
     {
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
     }
     .jscarousal-contents-vertical img
    {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: solid 1px #7A7677;
     }

```
.hidden
{
display: none;
 }
.visible
{
display: block;
}
.thumbnail-active
{
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1.0;
cursor: pointer;
}
.thumbnail-inactive
{
filter: alpha(opacity=20);
opacity: 0.2;
cursor: pointer;
 }
```

When I am using This slider on a single page it is working well and images are sliding but when I am taking the response using AJAX then the slider stops working.Due to some reasons I have to use this slider but can't seem to find the error.

Comment: There is alot of code here. This is a guess but instead of document.ready(function) try ajaxComplete(function)

Comment: It would be helpful if this could be placed into a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Iharby I don't know where to put external js in jsfiddle.

Comment: it's under External Resources @AK2

Comment: @Iharby I know that but don't know where to put online my code

Comment: Well I would check this: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ it might solve the issue, but you will have to test it and then update here.

Comment: @Iharby I have two AJAX functions on my page it is working on 1st AJAX function but i want it to work on second AJAX functions .

Comment: @Iharby Thanks man it finally worked.